# Zurb Foundation - how do I give rows a height

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation and I have 2 rows on a page. How do I make the rows different heights? I actually want to do this with more complicated rows but the problem is the same. I can change the width of columns but I cannot change the height of rows. I don't want the second row up against the first one - I want white space between them.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column small-12">
        <h6>line one</h6>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column small-12">
        <h6>line two</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

duh!

Use style="height:.."

I didn't realise that this could be done.